# MySQL CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS argument in command line

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to use Java to backup and restore a MySQL DB. I am able to backup the DB by using the command:

```
C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/bin/mysqldump -u root --password=password myDbName -r "C:/backup.sql"
```

and use the following Java code to execute it:

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p = runtime.exec(commandString);
```

After creating the backup, I would like to restore the DB with it. I can restore the backup file by the command:

```
C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/bin/mysql -u root --password=password myDbRestore<"C:/backup.sql"
```

The problem is, I would like to check if the database exists before perform the restore. Is there an argument for the MySQL to perform the `CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS`?

In other words, how to execute the following commands in one statement/in Java:

```
C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/bin/mysql -u root --password=password
create database if not exists myDbRestore;
use myDbRestore;
source C:\backup.sql;
```

Answer (score 0):

There's not really a direct way to achieve this, but you could try that:

- when you dump your database, pass `--no-create-db` to mysql dump. That will omit the create table statement.
- for restoring first run `mysql -uroot --password=password -e "create database if not exists myDbRestore" before you run the source of the dump file.

Please note that this might not be the most elegant way to do backups with MySQL for several reasons:

- you've got your credentials to mysql hardcoded in your java application. If you use e.g. github to store your code other people could see them.
- you're hardcoding the path to your MySQL installation. This programm will work on your computer now, but most likely not:

  - once you Update to a newer MySQL version that will not be installed to `C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/` anymore
  - on someone elses computer
  - on another operating system

For the above points and because of how you built it, I assume this backup is just for you locally? In that case, writing a simple `.bat`file might be a good alternative, as it's going to be much shorter and more straight forward?

Best,
Matthias

Comment: I have tried with the following command but does not work...
`C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/bin/mysql -u root --password=password -e "create database if not exists myDbRestore" myDbRestore<"C:/bakcup.sql"`. It gives `Unknown database 'myDbRestore'` message, and if I create the database manually, nothing happen after I run the command